# How to correct error: "Cannot convert value of type 'MyType.Type' to expected argument type 'Binding<MyType>'"?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am new to coding and get this error message:

> "Cannot convert value of type 'Tab.Type' to expected argument type 'Binding'"

What can I change to fix this? Here's my code:

```swift
enum Tab: String, CaseIterable{ 
    case house 
    case person 
    case message 
    case gearshape 
}

struct ContentView: View { 
    @Binding var selectedTab: Tab 
    private var fillImage: String { 
    selectedTab.rawValue + ".fill" 
    }
    var body: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack {
            
        }
        .frame(width: nil, height: 60)
        .background(.thinMaterial)
        .cornerRadius(10)
        .padding()
      }
   } 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I assume in your #Preview macro below the view, you're passing a value of type Tab to ContentView. Note that you're working with a Binding<Tab>, i.e., a two-way connection to some source of truth (e.g. a State) holding Tab. For preview purposes, you can create a constant binding using the static `Binding.constant(<your value for Tab in here>)` method. To bind to a state from another view, use the `$<some tab state>` operator. If you're unsure about what a Binding, a State etc. is, please familiarize yourself with SwiftUI dataflow ;)